# .htaccess ignoring flags, not matching next rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am building simple php mvc application, but have problem with .htaccess, it looks like it is ignoring flags and doesn't want to run next line

```
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule ^(en|sk)(\/)(.+)$ index.php?url=$3&lang=$1 [C]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [C]
```

my goal is to have multilingual site with adresses like http://example.com/lang/something, I used this as mvc skeleton [link to github repo](https://github.com/panique/mini) but it misbehaves

when going to `http://127.0.0.10`, everything ok
when going to `http://127.0.0.10/en/home` page also works
when going to `http://127.0.0.10/home` page not works

then when I removed first rule or swapped rules order, going to `http://127.0.0.10/home` started to work, but when going to `http://127.0.0.10/en/home` not, I undestand in first case here error was in place because app thinks "en" is controller, but what in second case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite condition is applicable for only immediate next `RewriteRule` hence 2nd `RewriteRule` is without any conditions.

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(en|sk)/(.+)$ index.php?url=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```